# How often are words used for outerwear in British English considered underwear in American English?

Tags: american-english, british-english, disambiguities

There are some differences between American English (AmE) and British English (BrE) and in the subject area of clothing, these can lead to some amusing mistakes. I have two examples of this where the AmE clothing term can cause some amusement (or even offence) to a BrE speaker. I would like to know if there are any that work the other way round.

The most obvious example is the **pants/trousers** comparison. An American friend, on arrival in the UK, complimented a native with the phrase "Nice pants!". Apparently they looked horrified and disappeared to check on the visibility of their underwear. The word "pants" is equivalent to "underpants" or "knickers" in the UK, and what you wear over them is called "trousers".

There is an item of clothing which is made to hold trousers up. I've just found out that in the US, the word is **[suspenders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suspenders)**. In the UK, the word is **"braces"** or **"galluses"**. It leads to the lovely alliteration "belt and braces". The BrE term "suspenders" means an undergarment to hold stockings up: suspenders attach to a suspender belt (which is a garter belt in AmE). Suggesting that someone whose trousers are falling down should wear suspenders could be taken the wrong way in the UK. It also leads me to question how the suspenders reference in [The Lumberjack Song](https://genius.com/Monty-python-lumberjack-song-lyrics) was interpreted internationally.

In both cases, a word that refers to an undergarment in BrE names an outer garment in AmE. I'm looking for any examples that work the other way round. I'd like to avoid any possible clothing-related faux pas in the US, or, indeed, any other English speaking nation.

---

To clarify, I can think of three examples of items of clothing that refer to outerwear in AmE but underwear in BrE. The examples are pants (trousers vs knickers), suspenders (braces vs garter belt) and vest (waistcoat vs, well, [vest](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/vest)). The question is are there any examples which are considered outerwear in BrE but underwear in AmE? Anything that is likely to raise a snigger or a wardrobe-malfunction check if you compliment someone on it.

Comment: It's probably true that there are still some Americans who snigger if a Brit says he's dying for a fag (cigarette). But Brits are used to the fact that Americans sometimes use different words than we do, so I doubt anyone would actually be "offended" if you unintentionally used an AmE rather that BrE word. Incidentally, in *The Lumberjack Song*, lyrics transcriptions notwithstanding, Whatsisname explicitly sings ***suspendies*** rather than ***suspenders*** to accentuate the "campness". Alluding to BrE ***undies***, I suspect.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, as a Brit, I know I sometimes inadvertently snigger at references to "pants" (I'm immature). I want to know how often I'm sniggered at in return, but lack the necessary AmE vocabulary. I've limited it to clothing because those are the two examples that spring to mind.

Comment: Perhaps that was a bit below the belt (pun intended! :), given that likely as not you and I are probably separated by several decades, as well as a (still significant?) gender difference!

Comment: I was told a yarn (very probably untrue) about an Irish woman on holiday who got a very funny look in a New York souvenir shop when she asked, "Do you have any novelty _rubbers_ shaped like the Statue of Liberty?" (Clothing of a sort, I suppose.)

Comment: If I'm honest, it was a comment on one on the answers to [this](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/127508/politely-calling-attention-to-unflattering-sight) question that inspired this.

Comment: My wife from Lancashire says "pants" for trousers. She also said of a pretty young woman who got promotion from a boss who had eyes for her, "Of course he gave her the job. He fancies the pants off her".

Comment: you need to include "fanny pack" for completeness :0

Comment: Stack Exchange doesn't handle requests for open-ended lists very well, but also what someone takes offense to is extremely fraught nowadays. Some would decry *agony aunt* as sexist or *Christian name* as exclusionary; others associate British terms with snootiness (not because they've met any Brits themselves, but because lots of snooty Americans affect European terms) and so roll their eyes at perfectly ordinary *aubergine* and *waistcoat* and indeed *football* (for association football).

Comment: @tmgr "Rubbers" means "erasers" in BrE, like a pencil eraser—she wasn't talking about clothing.

Comment: People _roll their eyes_ at 'aubergine'? _Really_? What about courgette? My wife's friend, as down-to-earth a Lancashire lass as you could ever hope to meet, has an aubergine peluche (I think Americans would call it a 'plushie') He has a little smiling face and is called Gine.

Comment: In the 1970s you heard about Brits going to Australia, renting a room, and being surprised when their landlady told them not to use "Durex" to fix posters on the walls of their rooms. Durex to Britons is the best known brand of rubber johnny, but in Oz it is a brand of sticky tape (like Scotch).

Comment: In the 1970s we knew about the Eggplant that Ate Chicago from Norman Greenbaum.

Comment: *Dickies* has a totally different use. In the US. it's a brand best known for heavy duty clothing for construction workers.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey And here as an American, I have no idea what you mean by "rubber johnny". Hah. (I'm guessing it's similar to what we call "tack"?)

Comment: A rubber johnny is a rather old-fashioned term for a condom.

Comment: You'll probably have to let the Americans know from your side - to that end, here's a list of undergarments: (Ladies':) bra, slip, full-slip, half-slip, panties, thong, boy-shorts, pasties, g-string, teddy, tap pants, bloomers, Spanx (brand name). (Men's:) wife-beater, guinea tee, vest, tee, t-shirt, tighty-whities, briefs, boxers, boxer-brief, jock-strap, banana hammock, g-string, . (Hope this helps)

Comment: Thanks @Oldbag, that's a great list! Some of those have the same ambiguities in BrE (i.e. I've heard of "teddy"). I had to look up "pasties" (and get past the pie definitions). It's looking a lot like this particular subject doesn't have an AmE to BrE snigger equivalent.

Answer (score 4):

It is common to find in lazily written "divided by a common language" blogs that Brits get shocked or angry at these things, but I find it very hard to believe that any Brit who has watched TV or been to the cinema in the last 60 years or so would be "offended" when a visiting American says "pants" for trousers. Or speaks of a "fanny pack" for that matter. We *know* that Americans use these words, and, it being 2019 and not 1819, we just smile a bit and make an easy allowance. When we go over there we take care not to say "I like faggots at lunchtime", etc, I suppose. Honestly. It's not a thing. We invented Mrs Slocombe for God's sake. I had never encountered the word 'gallus' before this thread.

Comment: I live in Scotland and i can say not only that the word gallus is used here but that Scots regard it as a distinctively Scots word and that it is one of those words that is often printed on tourist souvenirs as a typical Scots word. It is defined in [thefreedictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/galluses) with no reference to region. [Their encyclopaedia](https://encyclopedia.thefreedictionary.com/galluses) suggests the term was used in the C19. [DSL](http://www.dsl.ac.uk/entry/snd/gallows) has only the sense "gallows" which is presumably the quaint if metaphorical origin of the term.

Comment: @DavidRobinson the word in the question is "galluses" meaning "braces". Nonetheless, "gallus" is a fun word.

Comment: Perhaps I should have made it clearer. *Galluses* is the plural of *gallus*. This garment seems to be equally plural whether it's *braces*, *suspenders* or *galluses*. If its origin is indeed *gallows* then it's a double plural since *gallows* is in origin plural according to [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gallows) even though it's used as singular.

Comment: In "Hellfire and Herring: A Childhood Remembered", Christopher Rush says his uncle Billy described his playground gang, the "One-Gallus Gang". The prized method of holding up a boy's trousers was an snake clasp elasticated belt. Boys who lacked this had to use galluses. Uncle Billy's gang, he claimed, modified them to signify rebelliousness by cutting off one side strap and pulling the single remaining strap across their chests to meet a button, repositioned centrally, on their trousers. Rush says that he had "begun to suspect" Billy's tales, so maybe the singular use of 'gallus' is suspect.